# Is it possible to point Ant build.xml to M2 Repo 'Jar Files'?

Tags: apache, ant

Is it possible to point Ant `build.xml` to M2 Repo 'Jar Files'?

1. Let's say I developed a Maven project which downloads the JAR files using the POM file.
2. Is it even possible to point apache ant to my computer `.m2` repo instead of downloading the .JAR files manually and then pointing to the direct location of the download jar files?
   [image]

Thanks for you help

Comment: Check out the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422427/is-there-a-way-i-can-use-maven-repositories-to-add-dependencies-to-ant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes. You could create an ANT path as follows:

```
<path id="m2.path">
  <fileset dir="${user.home}/.m2/repository" includes="**/*.jar"/>
</path>

<javac .. classpathref="m2.path" ..>
  ..
```

But I would suggest you consider implementing dependency management within your ANT build process instead of relying on an external tool.

I would suggest [Apache ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) or alternatively the [Maven ANT tasks](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Aether/Ant_Tasks).