# How to download snapshot release?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, snapshot

I never download snapshot releases. But for implementing [a project](https://github.com/al2helal/TextPad) I have to use [RichText](https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX).

I want to download the [snapshot](https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX#snapshot-releases) release to use. Because of in the previous releases `import org.fxmisc.richtext.model.StyledSegment;` not found by the IntelliJ IDE.

I don't know anything about snapshot release, maven, gradle.
I just need the jar file of the latest release.

Please give me the direct suggestion for getting the jar file.

**Edit**
Now I want to run at least [RichText.java](https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX/blob/master/richtextfx-demos/src/main/java/org/fxmisc/richtext/demo/richtext/RichText.java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [ANT build tool](http://ant.apache.org/). Even if there is a way to use maven dependencies in the Ant (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422427/is-there-a-way-i-can-use-maven-repositories-to-add-dependencies-to-ant)) I would recommend to transfer the project to maven or gradle if you are not restricted to the usage of ant.

Nevertheless:

if you want to use [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/):

- [create new maven project in IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven.html)
- add required Sonatype snapshot repository and the snapshot dependency you want to use
- example [pom.xml](https://pastebin.com/dupi9jQb)

  ```
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.fxmisc.richtext</groupId>
          <artifactId>richtextfx</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <repositories>
      <repository>
          <id>sonatype-snapshots</id>
          <name>Sonatype Public</name>
          <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
          <snapshots>
              <enabled>true</enabled>
          </snapshots>
      </repository>
  </repositories>
  ```

if you want to use [Gradle](https://gradle.org/):

- [create new gradle project in IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html)
- example [build.gradle](https://pastebin.com/FKZ7cuJx)

  ```
  repositories {
      mavenCentral()
      maven {
          url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
      }
  }

  dependencies {
      testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
      compile group: 'org.fxmisc.richtext', name: 'richtextfx', version: '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
  }
  ```

**EDIT**

Maven follows [standard directory structure](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). You need to have pom.xml in the root directory, source java files in `src/main/java`, resources like png and css in `src/main/resources`. If you want to execute main class you can use [Exec maven plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html) where you can specify your main class. See [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwgZ2.jpg).

When you want to run your application:

1. optionally clean previous build - `clean`
2. build project - `package`
3. run the application with exec plugin - `exec:java`

Or if you prefer terminal you can use `mvn clean package exec:java`

Comment: If you use Maven, where is your `pom.xml`? You cannot use Maven without it.

Comment: @xstefank see [this](https://imgur.com/EEWjOKg) is it okay? why I have not `exec:java`?

Comment: @alhelal you need to declare plugin in the pom.xml - the yellow part in the image attached in the answer