# Adding Maven Dependencies to Ant

Tags: maven, ant

I'm trying to implement adding maven dependencies to my ant build using [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422427/is-there-a-way-i-can-use-maven-repositories-to-add-dependencies-to-ant). I beleive I have everything set up as indicated by the article but since it is not working I must be missing something. I am getting this error:

```
Could not load definitions from resource org/apache/maven/artifact/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.
```

My searches for this error seem to imply I an missing maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar. However, it is in the path indicated by the classpath. Can someone help be debug this? TIA.

I found at least part of the problem. I had the wrong file name in the classpath. It was maven-ant-tasks.jar and it should have been maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar.

Unfortunately I now have a different problem which I think implies a corrupt jar file.

```
Unable to obtain resource from /usr/build/lib/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
```

Downloading the jar file again did not help.

Answer (score -1):

Never mind. Apparently the Apache maven web site has a corrupt version. I downloaded it from the mvnrepository and that worked.